# creating a new variable by matching and repeating a value from a diffrent coulmn

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a large data frame with questions about friendship levels between students ("net1":"net6").

There are 121 classes of different sizes in the data frame.

"studentid" is the id of the student who is answering about a classmate and "alterid" is the id of the student that is referred to.

A sample of the data:

```
     studentid  alterid net1 net2 net3 net4 net5 net6 gender
1     30401001 30401001    1    3    3    3    1    1      1
2     30401002 30401001    1    3    3    3    1    1      1
3     30401003 30401001    2    3    3    1    3    3      1
4     30401004 30401001    3    3    3    3    3    3      2
5     30401005 30401001    1    3    3    3    3    2      2
6     30401006 30401001    2    3    3    3    3    2      1
7     30401007 30401001    1    3    3    3    2    1      2
8     30401008 30401001    1    3    3    3    3    1      1
9     30401009 30401001    3    3    3    3    3    3      2
10    30401010 30401001    3    3    3    3    2    2      2
11    30401011 30401001    3    3    3    3    3    3      2
12    30401012 30401001    3    3    3    3    3    3      1
13    30401015 30401001    3    3    3    3    3    3      2
14    30401016 30401001    3    2    3    3    3    3      2
15    30401017 30401001    1    1    3    3    3    1      2
16    30401019 30401001    3    3    3    3    3    3      2
17    30401021 30401001   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA      1
18    30401022 30401001    3    1    3    3    3    1      2
19    30401024 30401001    3    3    3    3    3    3      1
20    30401025 30401001    1    2    3    1    3    1      1
21    30401026 30401001    3    3    3    3    3    3      2
22    30401027 30401001    1    3    3    3    3    3      1
23    30401028 30401001    1    1    1    1    1    1      1
24    30401029 30401001    3    3    3    3    3    3      2
25    30401030 30401001    3    3    3    3    3    3      2
26    30401031 30401001    2    3    3    2    3    3      2
27    30401033 30401001    3    3    3    3    3    1      2
28    30401034 30401001    1    3    1    3    3    1      1
29    30401035 30401001    1    3    3    3    3    2      2
30    30401036 30401001    1    3    1    3    3    3      2
2385  30401001 30401002    1    2    3    2    1    1      1
2386  30401002 30401002   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA      1
2387  30401003 30401002    3    3    3    3    1    3      1
2388  30401004 30401002    3    3    3    3    3    3      2
2389  30401005 30401002    1    2    3    3    3    2      2
2390  30401006 30401002    2    3    3    3    3    2      1
2391  30401007 30401002    1    3    3    3    2    1      2
2392  30401008 30401002    3    3    3    3    3    3      1
2393  30401009 30401002    3    3    3    3    3    3      2
2394  30401010 30401002    3    2    3    3    3    2      2
2395  30401011 30401002    3    3    3    3    3    3      2
2396  30401012 30401002    3    3    3    3    3    3      1
2397  30401015 30401002    3    3    3    3    3    3      2
2398  30401016 30401002    3    3    3    3    3    3      2
```

I have a "gender" variable which is the gender of the student who is answering the questions.

I need to create an "altergender" variable that will be the gender of the student that is being referred to.

So if "alterid" end with 01 all "altergender" should be the gender of "studentid[1]" in the same class (row 1 in the data example), if altergender ends with 02 all "altergender" should be the gender of "studentid[2]" in the same class (row number 2386 in the sample).

I have tried creating a different object (without net questions) and in it changing "studentid" to "alterid" and then merging back to the data frame. It gave me the right results but created many new rows that I don't want.

I also tried different variations of ifelse but could not succeed in getting the desired result.

I admit that my function writing skills are very low so any help will assist me in solving the problem and will be a great opportunity to try and understand the logic behind it.

Comment: Since your "gender" refers to "studentid", you could `match` "alterid" to "studentid" and select the corresponding "gender"?

Comment: @user3821211  It is not clear what your desired result would be.  May be `with(dat, gender[1:2][match(alterid, studentid[1:2])])` where `dat` is the dataset

Comment: Thanks a lot alexis it sure did the job!